# Playing around in the registry windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, windows-registry, dpi, high-dpi

In trying to set up multiple displays,
I have found a setting in Windows 10 registry
that is in the following location;

```
    Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\Applied DPI
```

I know that DPI relates to Pixel Density per inch
The Current set value is: 0x00000060 (96) set as a REG_DWord
Can I change this to be higher?

I used a program last night Called CRU.exe that set new EDID Values in the registry. My New monitor has a resolution of 2560x1440 Which is higher then any values currently allowable in;

```
    Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\AdditionalModeLists\HDTV
```

But that broke both displays and I could not view either to change the settings back,
Luckily when I woke up It had reverted back to its old settings.
The problem I am having is that I can only mirror my Display onto the new monitor.
I cannot extend my desktop, It just shows blank and breaks the original monitor display.
When they are mirrored, My original PnP Display looks as normal but the WQHD Monitor its very poor quality, It should be 2560x1440px @ 144hz
But the best I am getting is 1280x1024 @ around 55hz
I have created the following entry in the HDTV Registry entry but am Unsure of Values that should be set within it

```
    I have created a new entry Called 2560x1440px144hz_16x9
      Created 6 new Q word's All other entries are 32 bit D words even   
        though I'm on a 64 bit system
        Q/D words Created are
          Default Reg_SZ (Value not set) This was already present.
          HorizontalPixels?
          HorizontalSync?
          PixelClock?
          Timingld?
          VerticalLines?
          VerticalSync?
```

Does Anybody Know What Values should be Set inside these entries?
I'm Thinking That My QWord should actually Be a DWord and 32 Bit not 64?

My Computer Specs are:

```
    Hewlett-Packard 3646h version 786G7 v01.14, 
    Intel Core 2 Duo E8400 CPU,
    Package: Socket 775 LGA,
    Graphics: Intel(R) Q45/Q43 Express Chipset 
              (Microsoft Corporation)(WDDM 1.1)
```

I have A monitor which Should be 2560x1440px but it is currently,
Only running @ a maximum of 1680x1050 also it should be running 144hz but is only achieving 75hz Picture looks terrible.

Comment: A [guide](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-connect-and-set-multiple-monitors-windows-10) to set up multiple displays

Comment: @spike_66 Thank you for the Guide, I will read through the whole of it, But from What I have read I'm still Unsure. Windows settings will not even allow me to drag and drop monitors in any order. it has chosen for me and they are locked in position. Nor will it let me adjust any settings for each individual monitor. Even clicking on advanced settings all setting are grey and none selectable.

Comment: @spike_66 Nor does Scaling have anything to do with actual DPI pixel ratio, the only thing this setting does is change Icon and text size Not what I'm looking for.